# Can't connect to phpmyadmin (HY000/1130): Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure what happened, but this is the second time this error has occured and i'm not sure why this happens. This is frustrating and time consuming. I had to throw away my databases and use the backup, but surely this can't be the long term solution for it?

I haven't done any changes and i was working fine with it previously.

Here is my log:

```
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2514484
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 2514493; transaction id 1391
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190829 22:33:59
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-08-29 22:33:59 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

and here is the log, when it worked:

```
2019-08-29 19:38:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-08-29 19:38:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-08-29 19:38:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-08-29 19:38:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-08-29 19:38:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-08-29 19:38:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-08-29 19:38:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-08-29 19:38:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=2514387
2019-08-29 19:38:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-08-29 19:38:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-08-29 19:38:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-08-29 19:38:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-08-29 19:38:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-08-29 19:38:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-08-29 19:38:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-08-29 19:38:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-08-29 19:38:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 2514396; transaction id 1391
2019-08-29 19:38:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-08-29 19:38:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190829 19:38:59
2019-08-29 19:38:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-08-29 19:38:59 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-08-29 21:53:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
```

I can see the IP is empty, but why? I have seen similar issues on here, but none of those answers seemed to work and throwing away my previous work and using a backup shouldn't be the solution and frankly getting fed up with XAMPP if this continues, as i have seen that this has been reported as a bug years ago and nothing has been done to fix this issue.

Comment: This is a restart with Crash Recovery.... Why does it need crash recovery?

Comment: This `[Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.` is a **Note** not an error

Comment: i have no idea. It was working fine and i went off and when i came back to use it, then this happened

Comment: Are you restarting Windows without STOPPING XAMPP?

Comment: No, off course i stopped XAMPP before shutting down or restarting

Comment: So look at mesages in this log from BEFORE this restart so we can identify why MySQL stopped

Comment: But anyway.... this looks like a GOOD restart and recovery. So exactly what do you see as a problem here

Comment: i just checked and it looks the same as now and can't seem to find an error here.

Comment: Add it to your question. So we can all see!